# R Function to predict which csv file would not be modified

Tags: r

I am trying to identify which types of csv files would not be modified in the future.
There are 540 csv files in one folder, and only 518 are modified. Basically, I wrote code to read and prepare this files to be modified by Java application and by running terminal on Linux they are modified.

This is what terminal shows:

data_3_5.csv

> Error in mapmatching or profiling!
>   No edge matches found for path. Too short? Sequence size 2

```
directory <- "/path/folder" 
directory_jar <- "/path/path.jar" 

setwd(directory) 

file_names <-list.files(directory) 

predict(file_names, model, filename="", fun=predict, ext=NULL,
const=NULL, index=1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I think, it doesn't work only for those files what have small length? Maybe just apply code which calculates the length of all columns in all  csv files and which would be small than n?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, and good job posting some code. You're pretty close, the `predict` function is used in modelling though, try this on:

```
directory <- "/path/folder" 
directory_jar <- "/path/path.jar" 

setwd(directory) 

## let's take out a little bit of protection to ensure we are only getting csvs
file_names <-list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE) 

## ^ ok so the above gives us all the filenames, but we haven't read them in yet... 
## so let's create a function that reads the files in and counts how many columns in each.

library(tidyverse)
## if the above fails, run install.packages("tidyverse")

## let's create a function that will open the csv file and read the number of columns for each.

openerFun <- function(x){                              ## here x is the input, or the path
  openedFile <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  ## open the file
  numCols <- ncol(openedFile)                          ## Count columns
  tibble(name = x, numCols = numCols)                  ## output the file with the # columns
} 

## and now let's call it with map, but map_dfr it's better cause we have a nice dataframe!

map_dfr(file_names, openerFun)
```

Once you have that, you can use it to compare against which files failed... hopefully that will help!

Comment: Apply code to count the amount of each ROW in all files and which would be small we may change  numCols <- ncol(openedFile) 
  tibble(name = x, numCols = numCols)   here to numRows?

Comment: `numCols <- nrow(openedFile)`. This is what you would change. If you wanted to you could `numRows <- nrow(openedFile)` and then tibble(name = x, numRows = numRows)